# Activity has been destroyed while adding a Fragment to a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I'm creating a `ViewPager` with a dynamic number of Fragments, I provide the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` of this `ViewPager` with a list of Fragments as in the following:

```
public class LightPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> myFragments;

    public LightPageAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fragmentManager);

        myFragments = fragments;

    }

   public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        return myFragments.get(i);

    }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {

        return myFragments.size();

    }
}
```

the fragments list is obtained when clicking some **button** on certain `Fragment`, So, i added the following method to this `Fragment` in order to adding this fragments list to the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`:

```
public void fargmenting(List<Fragment> fragments){

   ViewPager view_pager = (ViewPager) MyFragment.view.findViewById(R.id.lighting_pager);
   view_pager.setAdapter(new LightPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), fragments)); // this is where I'm getting the Exception

}
```

**Hint**:
 in my app I'm using `VerticalViewPager` not `ViewPager` but it's a **library** with the same behaviour of the `ViewPager` but with some modification that wouldn't affect the overall process.

And this is the **Log Error**:

```
05-07 11:51:02.404: E/AndroidRuntime(3174): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 11:51:02.404: E/AndroidRuntime(3174): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
05-07 11:51:02.404: E/AndroidRuntime(3174):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1365)
05-07 11:51:02.404: E/AndroidRuntime(3174):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
05-07 11:51:02.404: E/AndroidRuntime(3174):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:578)
05-07 11:51:02.404: E/AndroidRuntime(3174):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:161)
05-07 11:51:02.404: E/AndroidRuntime(3174):     at com.automation.standards.VerticalViewPager.populate(VerticalViewPager.java:965)
05-07 11:51:02.404: E/AndroidRuntime(3174):     at com.automation.standards.VerticalViewPager.populate(VerticalViewPager.java:811)
05-07 11:51:02.404: E/AndroidRuntime(3174):     at com.automation.standards.VerticalViewPager.setAdapter(VerticalViewPager.java:334)
05-07 11:51:02.404: E/AndroidRuntime(3174):     at com.automation.fragments.MyFragment.fargmenting(Lighting_Right.java:92)
05-07 11:51:02.404: E/AndroidRuntime(3174):     at com.automation.isolace.Lighting.assign_vertical_gangs_swipping(Lighting.java:502)
05-07 11:51:02.404: E/AndroidRuntime(3174):     at com.automation.isolace.Lighting.select_room(Lighting.java:403)
05-07 11:51:02.404: E/AndroidRuntime(3174):     at com.automation.isolace.Lighting$11.onClick(Lighting.java:351)
05-07 11:51:02.404: E/AndroidRuntime(3174):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
05-07 11:51:02.404: E/AndroidRuntime(3174):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
05-07 11:51:02.404: E/AndroidRuntime(3174):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-07 11:51:02.404: E/AndroidRuntime(3174):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-07 11:51:02.404: E/AndroidRuntime(3174):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-07 11:51:02.404: E/AndroidRuntime(3174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-07 11:51:02.404: E/AndroidRuntime(3174):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 11:51:02.404: E/AndroidRuntime(3174):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-07 11:51:02.404: E/AndroidRuntime(3174):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-07 11:51:02.404: E/AndroidRuntime(3174):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-07 11:51:02.404: E/AndroidRuntime(3174):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of efforts I finally did find the solution:

The Activity was destroyed when calling `setAdapter` because it's creating a new Object of the adapter (as I assign the adapter as new object):

`new LightPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), fragments)`

and that was destroying the old instance including the activity that it's initialization depended on this instance.

So that, I do split the `fragmenting()` method into **two** parts , the **first** part when calling it for the first time in order to make the first initialization, and the **second** part when only the data changed and no need to recreate a new instance of the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` :

```
private static LightPageAdapter lpa;
private static PagerAdapter adapter;

public void fargmenting(List<Fragment> fragments, boolean first_init){

   if(first_init){
      ViewPager view_pager = (ViewPager) MyFragment.view.findViewById(R.id.lighting_pager);
      lpa = new LightPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), fragments);
   }else{
      LightPageAdapter.myFragments = fragments; // here I'm setting the fragments manually instead of passing it into a new constructor
      lpa.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   adapter = lpa;
   view_pager.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Comment: Could you delete your answer and let someone else do it? Unfortunately your English is too bad for the answer to be useful :(. Or if you can rewrite it please?

Comment: @Radu well, I see that the answer English is ok, the problem is that it's quite complicated, so, you can refer to the part that you don't understand and I'll clarify it for you, and to make it easier to understand I split the answer into points and paragraphs, may be that makes a little sense for you

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat could you clarify a bit where are you using this method and why is ti necessary? I think this may be the solution for my problem but I cannot understand it.

Comment: @kike I'm using this method in all cases of fragmenting, but the difference is the flag I'm passing in the method called `first_init`, when this is the first init of the activity, I'm passing it with true to create the fragments, but when needing to just replace the fragments with another ones, I'm calling the method with false, so this flag is needed to be true only in the first time, and all the changes to the fragments later must have to be done with this flag = false